# Is there any working app to do screen recording in Flutter on tap on a button?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm looking for a working model of Screen recording plugin or package for Flutter. On tap a button, it should start the screen recording and show the timer that from how long the screen recorder is going on and it should run in the background as well. Please help me out and suggest some solutions.

Comment: Have you tried any packages? Please mention that so everyone get to know that what you have tried?

Comment: Did you find any solution for screen recording?